# Protect user login page with Basic Auth

Tags: users

Is it possible to make Drupal more secure by making LOGIN page private? I would like to make /user/login page private with Basic Auth so an user and password are needed before I get in that page.

Or is there another ways to make the login more safe? Goal is to prevent hackers to get in. Also if there's some module that helps on this it would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

From your question

> Is there another ways to make the login more safe?

Yes,try one of the following modules

[Login Security](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_security)

> Login Security module improves the security options in the login operation of a Drupal site. By default, Drupal introduces only basic access control denying IP access to the full content of the site.

[Secure Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin)

> Secure Login module enables the user login and other forms to be submitted securely via HTTPS, thus preventing passwords and other private user data from being transmitted in clear text. Secure Login module locks down not just the user/login page but also any page containing the user login block (or other forms that you configure to be secured).

Answer (score 1):

You could also:

- Define https protocol for the login page (and the backend) on the Vhost directives. see https://www.drupal.org/https-information. But secure login or password policy module seems great because they also take care of the cookie protection.
- Increase the passwords complexity (lenght, signs, etc). The module [Password policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy) could interest you.
- Setup fail2ban and create a jail for Drupal to ban recurrent attacker (see [Vincent article](http://www.vincentliefooghe.net/content/param%C3%A9trage-fail2ban-pour-drupal) for example)

Answer (score 0):

You may set up a Basic Auth on the /user/ URL.

See this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/532039/apache-basic-auth-for-a-particular-url

A proposed solution modified for this particular situation:

```
#set an environtment variable "auth" if the request starts with "/user"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/user auth=1

AuthName "Please login to access"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/path/to/my/.htpasswd"

# First, allow everybody
Order Allow,Deny
Satisfy any
Allow from all
Require valid-user
# Then, deny only if required
Deny from env=auth
```

Comment: Hey, when I add that to .htaccess it displays it to all of the pages somehow, what to do?

Comment: Also where to store .htpasswd that its safe directory?

Comment: In all pages or just in all /user/* pages? Safe directory for .htpasswd depends on your system, it should be usualy outside your Drupal root directoy. For example in /etc/apache (if you have root privileges). Also you can name the file as you want.

Comment: In all pages. I cant find the /apache folder either I know theres the certain directory that the htpasswd goes.

Comment: Tunic, I've get it to work, but which is the right place to put .htpasswd file if I cant fine /apache folder? I dont have rights to it anyway.

Comment: Put it in a folder you have permissions, better if it's outside your docroot. Is not important where it is as long as the right path to the .htpasswd is used in the AuthUserFile param of the .htaccess file

Comment: This almost worked for me but I needed a different order for the rules, like so: #  
    ```AuthName "Please login to access"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile path to file
    Require valid-user
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=AUTH
    Satisfy any```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 and 9, you can prevent anonymous access to the /user/login page using the [Disable Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_login) module. The module will require users to use an additional querystring and secret value for the querystring to access /user/login.

Admin user can set both the name of the QueryString and the value which will allow access to the login page.

For eg:

http://example.com/user/login

will give access denied.

http://example.com/user/login?key=secret

will allow the user to access the login page if key and secret are the name and value configured in the module.